# New Column for DateTime from Paramater

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have parameter date and wanted it to create a new column to my dataframe. Is there any way I can pass this parameter to my DF for my new column?

```
val date = "2020/01/01"
df.withColumn("DateTemp", date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign a constant value -

```
val date = "2020/01/01"
df.withColumn("DateTemp", date)
```

You can achieve this with [Lit](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-lit-and-typedlit-to-add-a-literal-or-constant-to-spark-dataframe/) -

```
df.withColumn("DateTemp", lit("2020/01/01"))
```

You can further cast your `lit` assignment as `lit("2020/01/01").cast(DateType)` if needed